# Is there a way to refactor a chain of UNIONs in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, unpivot, lateral-join

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'EntityName' AS [Column], EntityName AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE EntityName IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'AssetClass' AS [Column], AssetClass AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE AssetClass IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'VehicleType' AS [Column], VehicleType AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE VehicleType IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Strategy' AS [Column], Strategy AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE Strategy IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Bundled' AS [Column], Bundled AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE Bundled IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Geography' AS [Column], Geography AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE Geography IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Sector' AS [Column], Sector AS [Value]
  FROM dbo.Deals
  WHERE Sector IS NOT NULL
```

If I were to write something similar in a different programming language, I would create a list of columns and then iterate through that list.

Is there a way to refactor this SQL code to reduce the amount of duplication?

Comment: Just for info, UNION and DISTINCT are tautological operations, it's enough to use UNION since it distincts automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, here is one way to do it with `cross apply`:

```
select distinct v.col, v.val
from dbo.Deals
cross apply ( values 
    ( 'EntityName', EntityName),
    ('AssetClass',  AssetClass),
    ('VehicleType', VehicleType),
    ('Strategy',    Strategy),
    ('Bundled',     Bundled),
    ('Geography',   Geography),
    ('Sector',      Sector)
) v(col, val)
where v.val is not null
```

This is more efficient that multiple `union`s, as it scans the table only once, then unpivots - and also much easier to maintain (you just modify the `values()` row constructor).

Note that, for this to work, all unpivoted columns must be of the same datatype (otherwise, some casting is required) ; this constraint equally applies to your original query.

Answer (score 4):

GMB's approach is a nudge more performant +1, but here is an approach that will dynamically UNPIVOT virtually any table, view or query.

Added benefit ... There is no need to convert datatypes for the `Value` column

```
Select A.[ID]
      ,B.[Key]
      ,B.[Value]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select *
                  From  OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                  Where [Key] not in ('ID','Other','Columns2Exclude')
              ) B
```