# Unpivot and align rows for each field

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

How can I align the rows and attributes of each field in a table to appear in the same line, using the given table as an example?. Mark this all fields in this table are varchar so as to enable uniformity.

| STD | SUBJECT | MARKS | COMMENT | TDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST1 | MATH | 25% | POOR | 1/02/2021 |
| ST1 | ENGLISH | 88% | DIST | 2/02/2021 |
| ST1 | SCIENCE | 56% | PASS | 4/02/2021 |

The table should appear like this after unpivoting the contents in `[Subject]`:

| STD | MATH | COMMENT | TDATE | ENGLISH | COMMENT | TDATE | SCIENCE | COMMENT | TDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST1 | 25% | POOR | 1/02/2021 | 88% | DIST | 2/02/2021 | 56% | PASS | 4/02/2021 |

I tried with my code and got lots of errors, so maybe I could get some help to achieve the desired result.

```sql
         SELECT
             [MATH],
             [ENGLISH],
             [SCIENCE]
         FROM (
             SELECT
                 STD, stdn,
                 cont,
                 x,
                 SUBJECT
             FROM
                 [dbo].[Exam]
             UNPIVOT (
                 x
                 for cont in (COMMENT, TDATE)
             ) a
        ) a
        PIVOT (
           MAX(x) 
           FOR SUBJECT IN (
                [MATH],
                [ENGLISH],
                [SCIENCE],
            )
        ) p
        WHERE p.stdn IN (SELECT STD FROM [dbo].[exam])
```

Comment: I assume this is mssql? (your db should be a tag!) but why is this tagged "join" "case" "sql-order-by"?

Comment: nop is sql server sorry

Comment: I edited the tags (*but I was really suggesting that you! do that*) Don't indulge in "tag graffitti" just add the tags that are relevant to your question.

Comment: Using `PIVOT`, or doing any kind of transposition in SQL, is an anti-pattern (because SQL is fundamentally row-based, not columnar) - ideally this kind of _presentation layer_ task should be done by the part of your software that actually renders the table on-screen for your users (i.e. your HTML or report-generator lib) - Otherwise, do you have a _good reason_ for wanting to do this?

Comment: SQL Server is not well-suited to this because it expects that all columns getting pivotted/unpivotted are of exactly the same data type whereas you appear to be mixing strings (char/nchar) and dates here. This would be a task better suited to your application/frontend/reporting layer.

Comment: okay lets say i drop the tdate colum, how would i go about this problem

Answer (score 1):

i think i solved it when i used  MAX(CASE)

```
        SELECT [STD], 
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'MATH' THEN MARKS ELSE '' END) MATH,
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'MATH' THEN COMMENT ELSE '' END) COMMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'MATH' THEN TDATE ELSE '' END) TDATE ,
   
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'ENGLISH' THEN MARKS ELSE '' END) ENGLISH,
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'ENGLISH' THEN COMMENT ELSE '' END) COMMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'ENGLISH' THEN TDATE ELSE '' END) TDATE ,
    
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'SCIENCE' THEN MARKS ELSE '' END) SCIENCE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'SCIENCE' THEN COMMENT ELSE '' END) COMMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'SCIENCE' THEN TDATE ELSE '' END) TDATE 

    FROM [dbo].[EXAM]  GROUP BY STD
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivots for presentation purposes are not well suited to SQL and often better performed by a "front end" or "reporting tool" despite this, it is possible to pivot this data using T-SQL.

I assume that an unstated requirement is that the columns are presented in a specific left-to-right "block sequence" of "subject-mark-comment-tdate" so there needs to be a way to organize the columns in that sequence. A further probable requirement is that the pivot cater for an unknown number of total columns, for this you need "dynamic sql".

Note: This "unpivot" is complicated by the fact that there are different data types involved, one way to avoid this is to cast all data to strings or `sql_variant` (which is the approach seen below). Another (that I prefer) is to use JSON [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345264/2067753) but I wasn't also able to control the the "rnk" value as I needed for this query to formulate the numeric sequence of columns.

So, this is proposed:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + quotename(concat(c.column_name, cj.rn))
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
            cross join (
                select row_number() over(order by subject) rn
                from (select distinct subject from exam) e
                ) cj
            WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'Exam'
            AND c.column_name <> 'STD'
            order by cj.rn, c.ORDINAL_POSITION
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT STD, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                SELECT STD, 
                       concat(COLUMN_NAME,rnk) as COLUMN_NAME, 
                       VALUE
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT STD, 
                           CAST(SUBJECT AS sql_variant) AS SUBJECT, 
                           CAST(MARKS AS sql_variant) AS MARKS, 
                           CAST(COMMENT AS sql_variant) AS COMMENT, 
                           CAST(convert(varchar(10), TDATE ,120) AS sql_variant) AS TDATE,
                           dense_rank() over(partition by STD order by MARKS) as rnk
                    FROM Exam
                ) AS subquery
                UNPIVOT
                (
                    VALUE
                    FOR COLUMN_NAME IN (SUBJECT, MARKS, COMMENT, TDATE)
                ) AS unpvt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(VALUE)
                for COLUMN_NAME in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

| STD | SUBJECT1 | MARKS1 | COMMENT1 | TDATE1 | SUBJECT2 | MARKS2 | COMMENT2 | TDATE2 | SUBJECT3 | MARKS3 | COMMENT3 | TDATE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST1 | MATH | 25% | POOR | 2021-02-01 | SCIENCE | 56% | PASS | 2021-02-04 | ENGLISH | 88% | DIST | 2021-02-02 |

[see this as a working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LW0_Pyq7)

nb: As I ended up converting the date column into a string to control the format, you could replace the "as sql_variant" with "as varchar(100)"(length of 100 is a guess)

Comment: Why not use the conditional case expression with aggregate. `MATH = max(case when SUBJECT = 'MATH' then MARKS end)`. It is much simpler.

Comment: sure conditional aggregates are an option, answer away